# How to determine if object has been placed using placement new

Tags: c++, placement-new

Using the placement new syntax, I should be able to do something like this:

```
char *buffer  = new char[sizeof(MyClass)]; //pre-allocated buffer
MyClass *my_class = new (buffer) MyClass; //put da class there
```

Now suppose I just do the first line, but not the second. Is there a way that it can be determined in code whether the buffer has been allocated appropriately, but no object of type MyClass has yet been instantiated there?

Comment: Why do you need this? It does not seem right.

Comment: @ZDF As it turns out, as I looked at the problem more closely it turns out I likely don't. So the answer to your question seems fairly clear - inexperience... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code:

```
char *buffer  = new char[sizeof(MyClass)]; //pre-allocated buffer
MyClass *my_class = new (buffer) MyClass; //put da class there
```

To determine *dynamically* whether the placement `new` has been performed information about it has to be stored somewhere. The language does not provide that service. So you have to do it yourself, in one of two possible main ways:

- Storing the info in the buffer.
  For this case the buffer has to be initialized at allocation. E.g. just add `()` at the end of your `new` expression. Otherwise there is no way to guarantee that the buffer contents don't look like an object. Two sub-cases:

  1. By adding room for a flag in the buffer.
  2. By having the flag as a member of the object.
     In the case of a polymorphic class there will in practice be a non-zero vtable pointer, which can serve as flag.
- Storing the info externally.
  For this case the buffer does not need to be initialized at allocation. There are a zillion plus some possibilities, including

  1. A simple `bool` variable.
  2. A collection of pointers to all such objects.
  3. An audible signal emitted to a chimpanzee, which is later queried.

Answer (score 4):

The language doesn't provide any built-in mechanism to provide that information, at least none that I know of. You'll have to add your own bookkeeping code to track such information.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging purposes, you can add a special member `signature` to `MyClass` and set its value to a constant

```
class MyClass {
   public:
      MyClass() : signature(762347562374) {}
      bool isValidSignature() const { return signature==762347562374; }
   private:
      unsigned long long signature;
      <other members>
};
```

Then, check it as follows:

```
char *buffer  = new char[sizeof(MyClass)]; //pre-allocated buffer
MyClass *my_class = new (buffer) MyClass; //put da class there 
if (my_class->isValidSignature())
   <this means that the object has been allocated correctly, with a high probability>
}
```

You can put everything that's related to signature, inside a proper `#ifdef` so that is only runs in debug mode.

Comment: Why should one use statistical approach when a flag yields guaranteed behavior?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It seems that there is some trivial solution to the problem that you are talking about. I don't get it; maybe you should add an answer to explain what you mean by "a flag".

Comment: I hate classes which have a different (greater) size in debug builds

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a `static` table of `this` pointer values which you mutate in the constructors and destructor to `MyClass`. Then check this against a particular value of `buffer` when you need to.

Don't forget to consider the repercussions of move semantics. Will be tricky to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Not without tracking it yourself.

One solution would be to create a wrapper around [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

```
template<class T>
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    T* allocate(std::size_t count = 1) 
    { 
        return allocator_.allocate(count);
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void construct(T* ptr, Args&&... args)
    {
        allocator_.construct(ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        allocated_ = true;
    }

    bool IsAllocated() const
    {
        return allocated_;
    }

private:
    std::allocator<T> allocator_;
    bool allocated_;

};
```

Comment: How does this compare to just a `bool` variable directly?

Comment: Just thought it was a nice way to wrap things up.